# Finding vector fields with given properties

Tags: vector-fields

I am trying to find a vector field in two dimensions which points in the negative radial direction and has magnitude 1.

Obviously the gravitational field on Earth's surface looks like that but how can we find such a vector field? To have a magnitude of 1, I guess that $x^2 + y^2 =  1$ where $x$ and $y$ are the vector components, but how do we get to the vector field definition?

Comment: Consider a one dimensional case along the x axis, you can easily make a vector field point inward by using $(-x)\hat{i}$, then just divide by the length to get $\frac{-x}{|x|}\hat{i}$, and so whatever x is it points inward (though this really just simplifies to $\hat{i}$ overall in this simple case). Try applying that to a two dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates. Let $\hat{r}$ be the radial unit vector, then:

\begin{align*}
\vec{F}(r) = -\hat{r}
\end{align*}

is the required field. Now $\hat{r} = \cos \theta \hat{i} + \sin \theta \hat{j}$. Also, from basic trigonometry, you know:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
and $$\sin \theta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

So in Cartesian coordinate the field you want is:
\begin{align*}
\vec{F}(x,y) =  -\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat{i} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \hat{j}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: You could have gone straight to the answer without invoking trig  as $\hat r$ is defined as a unit vector pointing radially from the center$ \frac{x\hat i+y\hat j}{|x\hat i+y\hat j|}$